# HeaderFooter In Itext pdf generation jar

Tags: java, pdf, itext

In which version of IText pdf generation jar will support HeaderFooter Class ??

Answer (score 0):

The `HeaderFooter` class was to be found until iText 2.1.7, which is mighty old, not supported anymore and likely to include some critical bugs.

If using a later version, you should use the much better [PageEvent](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221)s to build headers and footers.